# The data input from input can not be displayed on the chart

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to output to the chart from the button_start, which is the arbitrary input data from the sensor_input, but I can not receive the value from the button_start and display it on the chart.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public double dt;
    public double t;
    public double[] RawAcX = new double[500];

    public void init()
    {
        dt = 0.01;
        t = 0;
        RawAcX = null;
    }

    private void sensor_input()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            RawAcX[i] = Math.Sin(t);
            RawAcX[i] = Convert.ToDouble(RawAcX[i]);
            t += dt;
        }
    }

    private void button_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sensor_input();
        graph_acX.Series.Clear();
        graph_filter_acX.Series.Clear();
        Series AcX = graph_acX.Series.Add("AcX");
        Series F_AcX = graph_filter_acX.Series.Add("F_AcX");
        AcX.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        for (int k=0; k < 500; k++)
        {
            AcX.Points.AddXY(k*0.1, RawAcX[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I can not receive the value from the button_start and display it on the chart._ What is the issue? Receiving or displaying? Now which is it? Does the chart have a ChartArea? What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Comments and explanations in-line.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //I moved the initialization of dt to the declaration
    public double dt = 0.01;
    //t will be initialized to 0 by default
    public double t;
    public double[] RawAcX = new double[500];
    //this method is never called so I commented it out
    //public void init()
    //{
    //    dt = 0.01;
    //    t = 0;
    //    RawAcX = null;
    //}
    private void sensor_input()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            RawAcX[i] = Math.Sin(t);
            //this seems unnecessary since RawAcs is declared as double
            //RawAcX[i] = Convert.ToDouble(RawAcX[i]);
            t += dt;
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sensor_input();
        graph_acX.Series.Clear();
        graph_filter_acX.Series.Clear();
        Series AcX = graph_acX.Series.Add("AcX");
        Series F_AcX = graph_filter_acX.Series.Add("F_AcX");
        AcX.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        for (int k = 0; k < 500; k++)
        {
            AcX.Points.AddXY(k * 0.1, RawAcX[k]);
        }
        //I get a sine wave on graph_filter and nothing in graph_filter_acX
    }
}
```

Comment: _Comments and explanations in-line_ Can't say I like that as it makes it hard to read and lets us search if and where any explanations are.

Comment: @TaW Sorry about that. When I have comments or explanations about specific lines of code rather than a general approach, I like to do it this way. I find it gets very wordy when I need to quote the line in the text portion of answer and comment there. I will try to avoid this pattern when I am answering on C# board.

Comment: Incode comments are fine with me when working code is being explained. But on SO we need to find out quickly about the errors in the OP, e.g. _You missed this or that_ etc... - But: Since he didn't evn answer my simple questions it may well be moot anyway.. - Tiny nitpick: SO is not a board; it is an archive and its main value is not in answering current questions but in storing those answers. I almost never ask question but look up in SO all the time..